Why is studying upper bounds for $|I_\delta(\mathcal P,\mathcal L)|$ useful?
A natural problem in incidence geometry is counting the number of incidences of points and lines. For example, if $\mathcal P$ is a collection of points in $\Bbb R^d$, and $\mathcal L$ is a collection of lines, then under different hypotheses on $\mathcal P$ and $\mathcal L$, we would like to know an upper bound for $|I(\mathcal P, \mathcal L)|$ in terms of $\mathcal P$ and $\mathcal L$, where $$I(\mathcal P,\mathcal L) := \{(p,l) \in \mathcal P \times \mathcal L: p\in l\},$$
i.e., a point-line pair $(p,l)$ is in the incidence set $I(\mathcal P,\mathcal L)$ if $p$ lies on $l$. However, it seems it is also of interest to study bounds on the size of $$I_\delta(\mathcal P,\mathcal L) := \{(p,l)\in \mathcal P \times \mathcal L: p \in [l]_\delta\},$$
where $[l]_\delta$ refers to the closed Euclidean $\delta$-neighborhood of the line $l\subset\Bbb R^d$, and $\delta > 0$ is a small positive parameter. For instance, it is known that if $\mathcal P$ and $\mathcal L$ are $\delta$-separated sets, then the following sharp estimate holds:
$$|I_\delta(\mathcal P,\mathcal L)| \lesssim \delta^{-1/3} |\mathcal P|^{2/3} |\mathcal L|^{2/3}.$$
Question: Why is studying upper bounds for $|I_\delta(\mathcal P,\mathcal L)|$ useful? What are some applications, i.e., what does a good estimate for $|I_\delta(\mathcal P,\mathcal L)|$ imply? Do we care about the limit as $\delta \to 0$?
Thanks for your insights!

Incidence estimates for $\delta$-tubes and $\delta$-balls are an active area of research right now. Often one needs to place some spacing assumption on the tubes or the balls (besides $\delta$-separated) in order to prove inequalities which are analogous to corresponding incidence estimates for points and lines. See for example the paper "Incidence estimates for well spaced tubes" by Guth, Solomon, and Wang for a beautiful proof by Fourier analysis.
Perhaps the most impressive application of such estimates is the very recent (2023) resolution of the Furstenberg set conjecture by Kevin Ren and Hong Wang. This was an open problem for many years with some preliminary bounds first proved by Tom Wolff. The conjecture itself concerns the dimension of a Furstenberg set of points.
Definition. A Borel set $E\subset \mathbb R^2$ is an $(s,t)$-Furstenberg set of points if there exists a $t$-dimensional set of lines $\mathcal L$ in the affine Grassmannian, such that for each $\ell\in\mathcal L$, $\ell\cap E$ is $s$-dimensional.
The main question is to prove a lower bound on the dimension of a Furstenberg set of points. Wolff popularized the Furstenberg set conjecture as a refinement of the Kakeya problem in his survey "Recent work connected with the Kakeya problem." Wolff gave some preliminary estimate for the dimension of Furstenberg sets of points, and conjectured the sharp dimension lower bound based on the Szemerédi–Trotter theorem.
In a nutshell, the main way that such $\delta$-discretized incidence estimates find their way into proving dimension lower bounds is by using the notion of a Frostman measure. Every $s$-dimensional subset $E\subset\mathbb R^d$ supports a probability measure $\mu$ satisfying $\mu(B_r)\le Cr^\sigma$ for all $r$-balls and every $\sigma$ arbitrarily close to, but less than $s$.
One step closer to the discrete picture is the notion of a $(\delta,s,C)$-set of points. A set $X\subset\mathbb R^d$ is a $(\delta,s,C)$-set if for every $r\ge \delta$ and every $r$-ball $B_r$, $|B_r\cap X|_\delta \le r^s|X|_\delta$, where $|\cdot|_\delta$ denotes the $\delta$-covering number; the minimum number of $\delta$-balls required to cover a set.
Given a $\sigma$-Frostman measure $\mu$ supported in $E$ (maybe an $(s,t)$-Furstenberg set of points) and a $\tau$-Frostman measure $\nu$ supported in $\mathcal L$, we can find a $(\delta,\sigma,C)$-set $E'$ of points in $\mathbb R^d$ and a $(\delta,\tau,C)$-set $\mathcal L'$ of lines contained in $\mathcal L$. Once we have such sets of points, we are in a position to apply what we know about $\delta$-discretized incidences $I_\delta(E',\mathcal L')$. In an ideal world, such incidence estimates give lower bounds for the number $\sigma$, and hence a lower bound for the dimension of $E$.
There are several study guides now available which were written during UPenn's 2023 Study Guide Writing Workship which describe some of the key steps and applications of $\delta$-discretized incidence geometry in the milestones towards  Ren–Wang's theorem, including one written by myself, Bright, Bushling, and Marshall on Orponen–Shmerkin–Wang's radial projection theorem, which was one of the key ingredients in Ren–Wang's theorem. One of the aims of our study guide was to trace a clear path between the Hausdorff dimension statement and the $\delta$-discretized incidence geometry Orponen–Shmerkin–Wang used in their proof.
A study guide by Fiedler, Hong, Ryou, Wu on Orponen–Shmerkin's $\epsilon$-improved Furstenberg set estimate, which was a key ingredient in Orponen–Shmerkin–Wang's radial projection theorem. Here, incidence geometry is the main tool used to prove the new dimension lower bound for Furstenberg sets.
